# How can I change Qt GUI widgets on a QMainWindow from a QThread which is a member?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have my main form made Qt Designer and inheriting from `QMainWindow` and the UI.  I need to have other threads running, and I need those threads to change things on the main form, eg progress bars, LCDs.

How do I give the other thread access to the widgets on the main form?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, that seems like a good way to go.  I've set up a signal and a slot, and have connected them, but the slot isn't ever being run.
I appear to be having the exact same problem as in the link provided by Flavius Suciu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you can use `thread->moveToThread(thread)`. As in the post Flavius linked. If your slot isn't called, the `connect()` probably failed. You link with a debug Qt, do you? Only that one prints warnings when connects fail.

Answer (score 3):

Using signal/slots.
Trolltech introduces from 4.x a threadsafe mechanism for signaling using for example the 
Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection parameter in connect() function.

For more details see:
http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-03/thread00260-0.html

Answer (score 3):

As Flavius Suciu has mentioned, you can use a cross-thread signal/slot connection. They can also carry arguments, however, if you don't pass just fundamental types or Qt types as signal parameters but, say, your own custom `struct`, you need to tell Qt about them this way:

```
namespace MyNamespace { // if any...
    struct MyClass { /* ... */ };
} // if any
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( MyNamespace::MyClass )
```

This allows `MyClass` to be stuffed into `QVariant`s, which is what Qt uses internally to ship copies of the signal arguments over thread boundaries.

You might also need to call

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyNamespace::MyClass>();
```

somewhere it's bound to be executed before any signal/slot cross-thread connection is attempted (e.g. in `main()`, or your `QThread` subclass constructor).

See the docs of [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)